# elevatezoom is working but element is not showing ( as I inspected html)

Tags: wordpress, elevatezoom

I am using elevatezoom for my Wordpress site. Even though I have set up everything correctly and even it render some html near the end of body tag. When I inspect the element, I see it is working but not really sure why no magnifying image or anything showing when I hover the image. It even worked 1 time but now I can't know why it is not working. Can anybody help me to detect on this url:

http://www.alanwaaronline.com/portfolio/ring-code-163195/

The image is the first image from the left, and the element for it rendered is nearly the the end of body which is zoomContainer class.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some css issue in your theme. adding the following css will fix the issue.

`.zoomContainer {
    z-index: 100;
}`